# Program quits while changing characters?

Tags: c, file, fopen, eof, fclose

I am trying to make a program that converts (Đ,Š,Č,Ć and Ž) Serbian(Latin) charecters to (D,S,C,C,Z) so my TV can recnognise them btw. 
NO IT's NOT A ENCODING ERROR, YES MY TV IS RUNNING THE LATEST SOFTWARE.

So I decided to make this command program that converts characters.
The problem is the target file stays unchanged, and it quits after this message:

```
Počinje konvertovanje.
```

Why does this happen?
The source:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
char c;
char filename[256];
int er;
int main()
{
    printf("\nUnesi podatak za prevoðenje:");
    scanf("%s",&filename);
    FILE* filepointer;
    filepointer = fopen(filename,"r+");
    if(filepointer == NULL){
        fclose(filepointer);
        printf("\nGREŠKA: Nije moguæe otvoriti podatak!");
    }else{
        printf("\nUspješno otvoren podatak.");
        printf("\nPoèinje konvertovanje.");
        proccess:
        if(c = fgetc(filepointer) != EOF){
            if(c == 0x9A){  // ZA Š
                c = 0x73;
                er = fputc( c , filepointer );
                if(er = EOF)
                    goto error;
            }else if(c == 0xF0){ //ZA Đ
                c = 0x64;
                er = fputc( c , filepointer );
                if(er = EOF)
                    goto error;
            }else if(c == 0x9E){
                c = 0x7A;
                er = fputc( c , filepointer );
                if(er = EOF)
                    goto error;
            }else if(c == 0xE8){
                c = 0x63;
                er = fputc( c , filepointer );
                if(er = EOF)
                    goto error;
            }else if(c == 0xE6){
                c = 0x63;
                er = fputc( c , filepointer );
                if(er = EOF)
                    goto error;
            }
            goto proccess;
        }
        if((c = fgetc(filepointer) ) != EOF){
            printf("Prijavljen EOF: Podatak se završava!");
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    return 0;
    error:
        printf("\nPrijavljen neoèekivani EOF,");
        printf("\nvjerovatno je neka greška!");
        return 1;
}
```

Platform:
Windows 7 Home Premium (x64)

Compiler:
Tiny C Compiler (x64)

Comment: Use `==` for comparision, wrap `c = fgetc(filepointer)` in parenthesis and remove the ampersand from the first `scanf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things.

**Point 1.** As per the `C` [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), in your code

```
if(c = fgetc(filepointer) != EOF)`
```

translates to

```
if ( c =  (fgetc(filepointer) != EOF) )`
```

which is not what you want. You should change that to

```
if((c = fgetc(filepointer)) != EOF)`
```

**Point 2.**

```
 if(er = EOF)
```

`=` is the assignement operator. To *compare* values, you need to use eqality operator `==`. Your code should be

```
if(er == EOF)
```

Note: If possible, please avoid `goto`. It is not a very good programming style. Try to make up a function and call that istead.

Comment: Thanks,sorry I am use to assembly :)

Answer (score 1):

You're getting bitten by operator precedence:

```
if(c = fgetc(filepointer) != EOF)
```

should be:

```
if((c = fgetc(filepointer)) != EOF)
```

Note that if you had compiled with warnings enabled (e.g. `gcc -Wall ...`) the compiler would have helpfully pointed out this mistake:

```
main.c:19:41: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]
         if(c = fgetc(filepointer) != EOF){
```

You would also have been warned about another mistake:

```
main.c:23:28: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]
                 if(er = EOF)
```

This line should of course be:

```
                 if(er == EOF)
```

---

A further problem - you're trying to modify the input file "in place" - this is generally a bad idea (any errors typically mean you are left with a corrupted original file). Furthermore, the way the code is currently written it won't do what you want (as you have seen). A better approach would be to write the output to a new file, and then on successful completion you can delete the old file and rename the new file.

---

As a bonus, some pointers on programming style:

- avoid globals
- don't use `goto`